# How to set visibility to a redux form field on value change?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-state

I am trying to set visibility to a new redux form field every time a user sets a higher number than allowed. So basically I am taking some data from a rest call, comparing the data to the one the user inputted into the field, if the number is higher than expected I am suppose to set visibility to a new field in the form.

my form:

```
const TaskForm = (props) => {
        
    const {fields: {title, hours}, handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, invalid} = props;
    const timesheetData = useSelector(state => state.timesheet)
    const [maxHoursExceeded, setMaxHoursExceeded] = useState(false);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit.bind(this))}>
            <div className="field-wrap"> 
                <label className="label" htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
                <Field name="title" component={titleInput}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field-wrap">
                <label className="label" htmlFor="hours">Hours:</label>
                <Field name="hours" component={hoursInput}  />
            </div>
            <div className={maxHoursExceeded ? "field-wrap": "field-wrap visible"}> // this visibility should change
                <label className="label" htmlFor="maxHours">Change max hours:</label>
                <Field name="maxHours" component={hoursInput}  />
            </div>
            <div className="btn-wrap align-right">
                <Button  className="btn"type="submit" disabled={invalid} onClick={props.onClose} >Create</Button>
            </div>
        </form>  
    );
    }
```

form validation:

```
function validate ( values, timesheetData, setMaxHoursExceeded ) {
    const {title, hours} =values
    const errors = {}
    if(!title || title.trim() === ''){
        errors.title = 'Title field is required'
    } 
    if(!hours || hours.trim() === ''){
        errors.hours = 'Hours field is required'
    } else if (isMaxExceeded) {
        errors.hours = 'Maximum hours has been exceeded'
        setMaxHoursExceeded(true) // <<<< the error >>>>
    }
    return errors
}


function isMaxExceeded (timesheetData, values) {
 //this function just checks the validity of the inputed data

    if(values.hours + timesheetData.timesheet.tasks.reduce((total, { hours }) => total + hours, 0) > timesheetData.timesheet.maxHours){
        return true
    } else return false 
}
```

The error I keep getting is "setMaxHoursExceeded is not a function" since I guess I am not passing the state function correctly.
Is this even a proper way to handle this problem? Because I feel like it's becoming quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of input hours and use useEffect to trigger hours_selected and check your condition

```js
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
const TaskForm = (props) => {
   useEffect(()=>{
      if(your condition){
         setMaxHoursExceeded(true)
      }
   }, [props.hours_selected])
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const selector = formValueSelector(props.form) 
    return {
        hours_selected: selector(state, 'hours')
    }
}
```

Comment: Only problem I am having is that "my condition" consists of the inputted hours and if I use props.hours_selected I get undefined.